# Request to join Azure Active Directory group via API

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there an API endpoint to request to join an Azure Active Directory group? I've found documentation on how to *assign* users, but not a way for users to self-service request themselves.

We have an external application controlled by Azure AD group assignments and want to provide a "Request to Join" button that'd submit this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently a way for users to create self-service requests to join a group via API. You can [use Microsoft Graph to add users to the group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) if the account adding the user has GroupMember.ReadWrite.All and Group.ReadWrite.All permissions.

Self-service group management options are listed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/groups-self-service-management

Comment: At minimum, I'd like to deep link the user to the page where they can request to join the group. For example: `https://myaccount.microsoft.com/groups/[GROUP_ID]`. However, when you open that link there is no "Join" button. But if you navigate to the same page by searching it from the previous `/groups` page then the button appears.